# Original image not saving?

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, gallery, media-library, images

When i'm uploading a picture, WordPress doesn't save the original image, just the thumbnails? That's why when i'm setting a featured image, the link is broken. Any help to to save the original image by uploading it via media library?

Comment: Hi Keith, welcome to WPSE. It sounds like something _might_ be off with file permissions, but that's just a guess. Worth checking. Can you try setting the permissions for `wp-content/uploads` to 755? If you don't know how to do that see https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Thanks Tim, problem solved. I guess the issue is with the file permissions.

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default image sizes of WordPress are “thumbnail”, “medium”, “large” and “full” (the size of the image you uploaded). These image sizes can be configured in the WordPress Administration Media panel under Settings > Media. This is how you can use these default sizes with the_post_thumbnail():

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'

the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)

the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );  // Other resolutions
```

for more information to see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thanks for your answer purvik7373, and welcome to WPSE, however this isn't what the question asks.